# How does a kernel panel driver specify the xstep value

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, framebuffer, lcd

I'm working on an LCD panel driver for an embedded device with a Atmel sama5d2 based micro-controller under Linux.

The kernel version I'm working against is 4.4 [as found here](https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91/tree/linux-4.4-at91).

I'm using the drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-lg-lg4573.c driver as a template for the one I'm writing.

The driver comes up and integrates with the framebuffer provided by the atmel device driver as expected.

The problem is, the image that is written to the framebuffer is reflected about the Y-axis when rendered on the LCD panel - it appears like the LCD panel rasterises the image from right to left.

The LCD DMA doesn't seem to have any facility to deal with this (i.e. setting a negative address increment value etc).

In a nutshell:

1. The FB driver exposes a memory area to blit images onto
2. The peripheral DMAs the content of this memory directly to the LCD data bus
3. The LCD panel displays the image reflected - mirrored - across the Y-axis

So the question is, how is this sort of thing normally handled? I would imagine that this sort of interface issues would be fairly common?

Comment: In general these issues come up when you are not initializing the driver with proper configuration. I think there should be a register which controls the orientation.

Comment: I couldn't find such a register om the datasheet. I would have thought it has to be a video mode setting (the possible modes are provided by the panel driver)

Comment: These issues mostly happen due to bad init sequences. I cannot provide you any other help. See if you can find an example code which uses the same hardware like you. Best of luck!